# Law of the iterated logarithm in Hilbert space

Tags: pr.probability

The standard law of the iterated logarithm expresses that if $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are iid real random variables with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$,
$$
    \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac {X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{\sqrt {2n \ln \ln n}} = \sigma
$$
almost surely. Together with the same result for $-X_1, -X_2, \ldots$, the same limit holds true with absolute values around the sum $X_1 + \cdots + X_n$.

Is there a corresponding result when the $X_i$'s take values in a Hilbert space, and the absolute values are replaced by the Hilbert norm?

Answer (score 3):

There are such versions of the law of the iterated logarithm even for independent random vectors in an arbitrary separable Banach space. See e.g. [Theorems 4.1 and 4.2](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256048928).

In the case when the Banach space is a Hilbert one, [Theorem 4.1](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256048928) implies the following:

> **Theorem 1:** Let $X,X_1,X_2,\dots$ be iid random vectors in a separable Hilbert space $(H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle,|\cdot|)$ with $EX=0$ and $E|X|^2<\infty$. Let $S_n:=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Then
> $$\limsup_n\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{2n\ln\ln n}}=\sigma$$
> almost surely, where
> $$\sigma:=\sup\big\{\sqrt{E\langle X,f\rangle^2}\colon f\in H,|f|=1|\big\}.$$

To deduce Theorem 1 from [Theorem 4.1](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256048928), one only needs to note the following two points:

(i) In view of [formula (2.5)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176995982), $\sup_{x\in K}|x|=\sigma$.

(ii) $E|S_n|\le\sqrt{E|S_n|^2}=\sqrt{nE|X|^2}=o(\sqrt{2n\ln\ln n})$, so that condition (ii) of [Theorem 4.1](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256048928) holds.

---

In the case when $H=\mathbb R$, Theorem 1 becomes the law of the iterated logarithm cited in your post.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I would be also interested in the minimal assumptions for such a property to hold.

Comment: @Wolfgang : I have added details showing that your one-dimensional law of the iterated logarithm extends almost literally to Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thank you again. About minimal moment assumptions, on the real line, the second moment is necessary and sufficient for the law of the iterated logarithm to hold. Do I understand correctly that it is the same in Hilbert space with the condition E(|X|^2) finite?

Comment: @Wolfgang : I don't know if the condition $E|X|^2<\infty$ is necessary here. I see that your posted question "Is there a corresponding result" did not say anything about minimal assumptions.